# ArcGIS and BigTIFF's

Tags: arcgis-desktop, bigtiff

At some point ArcMap creates a BigTIFF rather than a normal TIFF.  BigTiFFs don't work in many programs - in my case AutoCAD.

What is the filesize where ArcMap creates a BigTIFF rather than normal TIFF.  Is there anyway to turn this off?

Comment: Above 4 GB BigTIFF is the only option. With compressed TIFFs ArcMap may deside to switch to BigTIFF earlier if it believes that the limit may be hit. Why not to let ArcMap to do the job and split the BigTIFF into pieces afterwards if needed for example with gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html.